# How can you select from users based on an array of uuids?

Tags: postgresql, uuid, pg

If I query postgres in heroku, it works fine:

```
select * from users where users.user_id in ('', '')
```

but if send the request via postman to index.js it works only if there is one element instead of $1:

```
select * from users where users.user_id in ($1)
```

I tried casting:

```
users.user_id::text 
users.user_id in ($1::text
```

and

```
= any( array ([]);
```

Answer (score 2):

First concatenate your UUIDs into a string with `,` as a delimiter and then pass it as a parameter to this query:

```sql
select * from users where users.user_id = any(string_to_array($1, ',')::uuid[]);
```

or this one:

```sql
select * from users where users.user_id = any(('{'||$1||'}')::uuid[]);
```

This is a more or less generic approach that can be used in other similar cases too.